# Getting different latitude and longitude for same address line

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google API for getting latitude and longitude of address,

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address
, bounds: map.getBounds() },
function (results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  Lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
  Long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
});
```

but for same address some times I get value : Latitude=33.189967 and longitude=-96.7333 which is more correct,
and other times I get array of Latitude and Longitude from which I pick up the first and the value I get is Latitude=41.920 and Longitude=83.41.
The address that I am currently using is '1550 South Custer Rd'.
Please help me some one.

Comment: Do you get different results with the same bounds or with different bounds?

Comment: I actually tested it, after removing the bound statements also, but it was still giving me the same result, so I guess bounds, is not a problem, but if I append, City/Zipcode behind street address than I get proper result, but in my case, I am suppose to get Lat Long only from street address

Comment: You seem to be mixing things up somewhere because (33.189967, -96.7333) is in Texas while (41.920, 83.41) is in China, and the geocoder is unlikely to return so vastly different results on an intermittent basis. Try to double-check the request you're sending and perhaps post a jsFiddle demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Hi marcelo, please find my comment below, I am too getting the same 4 results

Answer (score 0):

I get [4 results](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=1550%20South%20Custer%20Rd&geocode=1) for that string:

```
Found 4 results
[ 0 ]: 1550 South Custer Road, Monroe Charter Township, MI 48161, USA (41.9200564, -83.41902479999999)
[ 1 ]: 1550 South Custer Road, McKinney, TX 75070, USA (33.189967, -96.73350699999997)
[ 2 ]: 1550 South Custer Road, Spokane, WA 99223, USA (47.6389694, -117.34156009999998)
[ 3 ]: 1550 South Custer Road, Custer, MI 49405, USA (43.9296513, -86.21892639999999)
```

I don't know how you expect the Geocoder to know which of the answers is "more correct" as they all contain that exact string.  Perhaps you need to include more information (like the town or the state), or process the results to determine the one that is in your area of interest.

Comment: Yes exactly, this is what I am trying to say, I too am getting the same result, even today, when I tried to search for City "FRISCO", using the google API, it returned me Latitude and longitude as "Lat: 35.2298559,Long: -75.6324876", which is not correct, but when I try to Search it as "FRISCO,TX" then it returns me "Lat: 33.1506744,Long: -96.8236116", which is the correct value, so I am all stuck up, guys some one help me.Why is google API behaving like this?

Comment: How else would you expect it to behave?  There are 4 results that exactly match the search string.  Without any other information, there is no way to order them.  If you know the area you are searching in, you can filter them on distance from that area (or with a bounds), but the API can't.

Comment: Ya, but my requirement is, that I need to provide the user to provide any of the four parameters namely; street address, City, State, Name and Zipcode.

Comment: Then you can't implement that functionality.  Someone needs to provide more information.  Do _you_ know the area the result will be in?  If not, you will need to ask the user to choose between the results that match the query.

Comment: Currently, I only know, that I have to locate addresses in US

Comment: Then you need to implement a ["Did you mean"](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/didyoumean.htm) type function (the linked tutorial is from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial, but the concept for v3 will be the same).